# What does "/" signify in split(self, /, sep=None, maxsplit=-1)?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

> ```
> str.split = split(self, /, sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
>     Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string.
>
>     sep
>       The delimiter according which to split the string.
>       None (the default value) means split according to any whitespace,
>       and discard empty strings from the result.
>     maxsplit
>       Maximum number of splits to do.
>       -1 (the default value) means no limit.
> ```

The `/,` which would seem to be a 2nd argument is a new notation to me.  What is it doing there?

Answer (score 1):

From [What's New in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters):

> **Positional-only parameters**
>
> There is a new function parameter syntax `/` to indicate that some function parameters must be specified positionally and cannot be used as keyword arguments.
>
> In the following example, parameters `a` and `b` are positional-only, while `c` or `d` can be positional or keyword, and `e` or `f` are required to be keywords:
>
> ```
> def f(a, b, /, c, d, *, e, f):
>     print(a, b, c, d, e, f)
> ```
>
> One use case for this notation is that it allows pure Python functions to fully emulate behaviors of existing C coded functions.